# eval() suddenly not working in all my python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I've been using Python 2 for several months now, and commonly use eval() to dynamically set variables. For example:

```
num_ls = [1,2,3]
let_ls = ['a', 'b', 'c']

what2plot = 'num'
list2plot = eval(what2plot + '_ls')
```

Today, all of my code written this day suddenly hits an error when I use eval().

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       list2plot = eval(what2plot + '_ls')
>
> File
>   "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/computation/eval.py",
>   line 266, in eval
>       ret = eng_inst.evaluate()
>
> File
>   "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/computation/engines.py",
>   line 76, in evaluate
>       res = self._evaluate()
>
> File
>   "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/computation/engines.py",
>   line 123, in _evaluate
>       return ne.evaluate(s, local_dict=scope, truediv=truediv)
>
> File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py",
>   line 789, in evaluate
>       zip(names, arguments)]
>
> File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py",
>   line 686, in getType
>       raise ValueError("unknown type %s" % a.dtype.name)
>
> ValueError: unknown type unicode1792

Comment: You shouldn't be using `eval()` in the first place. Also, you have a typo. You wrote `what2pot = "num"` instead of `what2plot = "num"`

Comment: What do you mean, you "commonly use eval()"?! You should (almost) never use eval.

Comment: "commonly use eval() to dynamically set variables." **do not do this**. It is slow, inefficient, and asking for bugs.

Comment: My coworker has made the observation that you can't ask a question on StackOverflow without getting into a morality argument, and this is the second time I've seen it in just the last hour. Regardless of whether this is a good idea or not, the problem seems real and could use an answer. Why would `eval` fail in this fashion?

Comment: Given the traceback, there is a *lot* of context missing from the code you posted, so it's going to be hard to explain what, exactly, is happening. The advice stands, though: *stop using `eval` like this*.

Comment: Would love to know *why* I shouldn't be using eval() like this. What are good alternatives? Regardless, the code I described above using eval() spontaneously started spitting out this error...

Comment: @pavlov See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for some discussion on `eval()`. For example, in the code you posted, why not just use a dictionary that maps possible values of `what2plot` to their matching lists?

Comment: Thanks! Looks like using a dict will be faster than eval, and better for debugging purposes? Makes sense, although when I use eval() it's always at the start of a small block of code I using for plotting data or something, so speed differences will be trivial and debugging isn't really problematic in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't working as you expect because you're not running the normal builtin `eval` function, but instead a function from `pandas`. You probably have a `from some_module import *` statement that's bringing the pandas `eval` function into your namespace where it hides the builtin function.

There are a variety of ways you can solve this.

The simplest might be to just not do that import. Another option would be to do `del eval`, which will remove the imported function from your namespace, allowing the builtin function to be visible again. You could also import it again from the `builtins` module (or `__builtin__` for Python 2).

But a better approach is probably to not use `eval` at all. It's unsafe, slow and hard to debug if you encounter any issues. A much better alternative would be to use a dictionary to map between your strings and lists:

```
num_ls = [1,2,3]
let_ls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
selector_dict = {'num': num_ls, 'let': let_ls}

what2plot = 'num'
list2plot = selector_dict[what2plot]
```

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly the issue and this is a clear alternative. Thanks!